# Always show the keyboard input on screen

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard

Is there a way to force keyboards to show their whole onscreen input (and, by the way, how is this correctly called?). I'm talking about the one that appears when you don't have enough space (or at least when the device decides it), like the white input on this picture:

[image: A whole onscreen input with keyboard open. Galaxy Note 3]

I'd like it to be even on portrait screens of an app.

I've been searching for this, but it turns difficult to search something you don't know how it's called.

Edit: I forgot to tell, this should work in a Cordova app.

Comment: The on-screen keyboard aka soft input method.

Comment: Thanks @HischT. I've researched again and still nothing useful. No clue on your side for this for a Cordova app?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imm.showSoftInput(autoSuggestionTextView,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

Comment: Huh, sorry I forgot to tell, but this should work on a Cordova app =/