# disable "done" button on numberDecimal keyboard android?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a calculator app in android and have set the keyboard to always be open in the manifest but if you press the done button it still closes.
is there any way to override this?

the code i have used in manifest:
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"

Comment: You mean the DONE button of the keyboard ?

Comment: I think you need to add following things in your manifest android:imeOptions="Done" 
android:singleLine="true"

Comment: yeah the done button on the keyboard. i want the keyboard to be always visible with no way of closing it. the done button is my obstacle

Answer (score 1):

You can use Handle and Runnable to enable keyboard ....  with this code in Runnable:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(getCurrentFocus(),InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

But I think you should create layout replacement keyboard.

:)

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991480/always-show-the-keyboard-input-on-screen) and edit it because

```
imm.showSoftInput(autoSuggestionTextView,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

is error.